# Link html to css doesn't work on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with linking html to CSS. It doesn't work on Google Chrome, but it does on IE. Is there anything wrong with it. By the way, I downloaded the newest version of Google Chrome moments ago.
This is my html:

```css
 body{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  float:left;
}
h1{
  font:"courier new"
  size:14px;
  color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Alvex"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/test.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Nothing here</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Make sure your path is correct

Comment: I mean it works on IE man. Double checked it!

Comment: Are you using HTML 5? Post your folder structure

Comment: Yes, I am. What about it?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Then What is it showing in the chrome browser?

Comment: Don't bother guys. I found the problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is working in IE then path must not be an issue.
Did you check network tab in chrome developer tools? See if the .css file loads.

Comment: Okay... Thank you! I guess I have to turn off my adblock :D

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/test.css"/>
```

use like above

Comment: I don't think so, because my css file is in CSS folder and html is in HTML folder so it must be "../CSS" right.

Comment: then there is no issues about
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/test.css"/>
only thiong that need to check is file name and path
u can check it by chrome console. there it ll show what the error is...(with the path u specified for the css)